# Understanding masking of Byte in Java

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I was trying to save some space in a program and needed to use byte, I got on to a code that looks like this

```
private static final long MAX = 1000000000L;
private static final long SQRT_MAX = (long) Math.sqrt(MAX) + 1;
private static final int MEMORY_SIZE = (int) (MAX >> 4);
private static byte[] array = new byte[MEMORY_SIZE];

private void getbit(Long i)
{
byte block = array[(int) (i >> 4)];
byte mask = (byte) (1 << ((i >> 1) & 7));
return ((block & mask) != 0);
}
```

I cant understand what this means? In block why are we using i >> 4 should it not be i >> 3 since each byte is 8 bits? I also dont get what mask is doing?
I'm just getting started with byte's, any links to sources will be helpful

Here is some context - [Source Code](http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/eratosthene_en.php)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the lowest 8 bits of 'i', this is what I can gather (where the MSB is bit 7 and the LSB is bit 0):

- The value in the top 4 bits of 'i' represents an index to 'array'.
- The value of 'block' is set to the value located at the above index in 'array'.
- The value in bits 1-3 of 'i' represents a bit index to be masked out (the function will return true if the bit at that index in 'block' is 1).
- Note: Bit 0 of 'i' seems to be unused.

I know that's not a specific answer, but I hope it helps to point you in the right direction.

I didn't look at the context source code though.

Comment: thankx , i made an edit to add more information , take a look,i am starting to understand it, i wonder if this code would work the same way if i used int instead of long for "i"